# How to get Play current when using it in a trait?

Tags: scala, playframework

I'm trying to migrate my older play application to the new play version where you use DI to get the Play.current value.

How can I use an injected Application when I am currently using it in a trait like this:

```
trait SomeTrait {

  lazy val someThing = WrapApp(Play.current)
}

@Singleton
class MyApi @Inject() (currentApplication: Application) extends SomeTrait {

}
```

**I'm not sure how to pass the play.api.Application instance to my trait now?**

Comment: Injecting the entire `Application` is generally a bad idea, because it makes the component hard to test. Instead, think about what specifically you trait depends on and inject that (eg. `Configuration`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
trait SomeTrait {

  def currentApplication: Application

  lazy val someThing = WrapApp(currentApplication)
}

@Singleton
class MyApi @Inject() (override val currentApplication: Application) extends SomeTrait {

}
```